# Firebase authentication rules using array elements

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase with react native. In my app I allow users to share content with: read, copy or modify permissions, with either specific users or All.
Since Firebase does not provide an OR function for queries, I'm using an array to store the user:permission combinations, so that I can use the array-contains-any capability to query like this

```
.where("access", "array-contains-any", [user_id, `${user_id}:R`, `${user_id}:C`, `${user_id}:M`, "All_R", "All_C", "All_M"])
```

This allows me to query all content that is either owned by user_id OR shared to user_id OR shared to "All" with either R, C OR M permissions.

Now I want to do something similar for the authentication rules, (so that only users with "M" permission can modify etc.) by comparing the authenticated user ID with the user IDs in the array. In order to do that it would require a capability similar to "array-contains-any" and string concatenation for authentication rules.

Is that possible or do I need to do something different?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, this would be a good starting point: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I see authentication rules examples with fields, but not with arrays. In addition I would need string concatenation and wildcards to match both user_id and permission in the array. e.g. allow write if access contains request.auth.uid + ":M". The lack of examples with arrays and string concatenation makes me think that it may not be possible to do it that way, and I may need to change my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a few tests, and think I got a subset of the types you have working. I'll walk through the steps below, so that you can build from it at the end.

---

First step is to make this query work:

```
ref.where("access", "array-contains", user_id)
```

This is fairly easy to secure with:

```
allow list: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.access;
```

So anyone can read the document if their UID is mentioned in the `access` array.

---

The next step is to allow this query:

```
ref.where("access", "array-contains-any", [user_id, user_id+":R"]);
```

When we run this against the earlier rules, it is not allowed. That is because we're requesting a value that the rules are not aware of.

To make it work, change the rules to:

```
allow list: if request.auth != null && (
  request.auth.uid in resource.data.access || 
  request.auth.uid+":R" in resource.data.access
);
```

So now the conditions in the code and in the rules match again, and the read is allowed.

---

If we add another condition for the all-access rules:

```
ref.where("access", "array-contains-any", [user_id, user_id+":R", "All_R"]);
```

Then once again with the above rules our permission is denied, because we have a value in the query that the rules don't know.

To fix it, we check for that value in our rules too:

```
allow list: if request.auth != null && (
  request.auth.uid in resource.data.access || 
  request.auth.uid+":R" in resource.data.access ||
  "All:R" in resource.data.access
);
```

And with those rules, the query succeeds again.

---

At this point you can add your other conditions in here, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that works! BTW, In my app, "R" means that a document is read-only (a user that is not the owner, cannot make a copy or update it). "C" means a document can be read and copied to a new document, but not updated (only the owner can update it), and "M" means the document can be read, copied to a new document or updated. So correct me if I'm wrong, but Firebase rules can help me with reading and writing permissions, but the app will need to ensure that read-only documents are not copied, i.e. written to new documents or updated. Are there rules based on the value of data being written?