# rules for rbac using firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a role based access control using reactjs and firebase. My plan is to use the built-in authentication methods (email and password and google auth). The uuid will be saved in a collection called `users`.

I won't be using custom claims since I'll be storing a lot of data in `users` collection i.e profile picture, username, first name,last name etc.

So along with all this data I'm going to store another property called `isAdmin` which will be boolean value.

My users will be able to

- register,
- login
- update profile
- create posts
- edit/delete own post
- make post public/private
- make collection of posts and make that collection private or public

My admin will be able to:

- login
- view user data
- delete any user post/collection no matter it's visibility(private/public)
- List item

Anyone not signed in will be able to:

- View any public post or collection

This is the rules that I have written so far:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create
      allow read
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId || request.auth.token.isAdmin == true
    }
    match /posts/{postId}{
        allow read
    }
    match /collection/{collectionId}{
        allow read
    }
  }
}
```

I've no idea if I can make public/private using firebase and if any of my rule is correct. Need some insight.

**Update 1:** This is my re-written rules for firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isPublic(){
        return resource.data.visibility == "public";
    }
    function isAdmin() {
      return request.auth.token.role == "admin";
    }

    function isUser(userId) {
      return request.auth.token.role == "user" && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /posts/{post} {
      allow write: if isAdmin() || isUser(userId); // only admins and users themselves can write
      allow read: if isPublic(); // any body can read if the visibility is public
    }
    match /users/{userId}{
        allow read: if true; // anyone can see a user
      allow write: if isAdmin() || isUser(userId); // only the user themselves or the admins can write
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned above only the user who created a post will be able to write his/her own post so I guessed I'll need to pass the `userId` as well but the line: `allow write: if isAdmin() || isUser(userId);` is throwing in errors. How can I pass the `postId` and the `userId` at the same time to the match function?

Comment: This is quite broad, making it unlikely that someone can help efficiently and effectively. It's more likely we can help if you show the code for one use-case that doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: Can you atleast provide an example of or proivde rules where the admin can read/delete/update user data?

I guess I can take it from their.

I would've created my own custom backend but this project will be deployed for general people to use and I'm not comfortable with the authentication part

Comment: Some previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60454666 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63798637

Comment: Hey, I've checked both the posts and re-written the rules. can you help me with the error please?

Comment: What error do you get? Please show this in the question. Also please show the minimal code with which we can reproduce that error, and I recommend logging the values that your rules check in the code - so that we can all see that the conditions of the rules are met by the code (which is required for the read/write to be allowed).

Comment: Hey when I was copying the code and error I saw the mistake I made. I'll post the new rules here

Comment: Good to hear  If you were able to solve the problem you had, please post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Up until now everything works fine, I'll change the answer if I see any problem as soon as I created my frontend.

I've also provided comments for better understanding:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // anyone can view the user
    // only the user who created the account and admin can edit accout
    // only the user who created the account and admin can delete accout
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow create: if true
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId // check for admin
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId // check for admin
    }
    
    // anyone can view the link if it's public
    // only the author of the link and admin can edit/update/delete the link
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
      allow read: if true && request.resource.data.visibility == "public"
      allow write: if request.resource.data.author_id == request.auth.uid // check for admin
      allow delete: if request.resource.data.author_id == request.auth.uid // check for admin
    }
    
    // anyone can view the collection if it's public
    // only the author of the link and admin can edit/update/delete the collection
    match /collections/{collectionId}{
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
      allow read: if true && request.resource.data.visibility == "public"
      allow write: if request.resource.data.author_id == request.auth.uid // check for admin
      allow delete: if request.resource.data.author_id == request.auth.uid // check for admin
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:** After testing the rules work. I strongly advise anyone who want to take help from this answer create individual functions like `isAdmin()` and `isOwner()` etc. Clears a lot of the clutter